# Display book cover for recommended reading

Tags: discussion, feature-request, developer-story

On the developer story at the end is a section **Recommended Reading** if the book has a cover associated with it can that be displayed instead of the generic one that is currently displayed:

[image]

Amazon's web api can return this information and the looks would be quite appealing.

Comment: Great when will it be released?

Comment: Is 6-8 weeks a good answer? :) I can't give a date, we're building so many things at the moment on the developer story, but ASAP hopefully!

Comment: Great looking forward to it.  6-8 weeks is too long, 6-8 days for such a request is much more doable :).

Comment: Isn't there a danger that people will start *judging* the books based on that superficial information?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, hopefully people know not to judge a book by it's cover... ;)

Comment: @CaptJak: Yup, that was the joke. Thanks for explaining it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You'll be pleased to know that we already planned to build that. :)

Comment: Is this coming out yet?

Comment: @JonH Not yet, probably 6-8 weeks :)

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Any updates on this? 2019

Comment: Any Updates on this?