# How do I get book covers displayed for the Developer Story?

Tags: support, developer-story

I'd love to get the covers of the books on my Recommended Reading. How do I get that?

This is how it currently looks:

[image]

Comment: I was wondering this myself.

Comment: I asked this back in april: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322078/display-book-cover-for-recommended-reading this was supposed to be implemented months ago.  The response back was 6-8 weeks...I wonder if they meant 6-8 months (even we've gotten to the 6th month).  Maybe they meant 6-8 years.

Comment: This is not implemented yet, for a few reasons, one of which is that we want to find a canonical source for the covers, similar to crunchbase for the companies.

Comment: @Sklivvz While I really like the idea of individual covers, please make sure there is a way to overwrite them manually or at least switch back to the default icon. I think that having a set of book covers in different colors and/or with images would create a mess and draw attention away from the actual titles and user summaries. Maybe rendering the title onto a plain white background should also be an option, if you like the idea.